# RxJava - main kills observable threads

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java

Why main thread is killing my rxJava thread?

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    Observable.just(10)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .subscribe(i -> print(i));
    Thread.sleep(100);
}

private static void print(final int i) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch(final InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

`print` method is blocking the thread for 5000 millis and I thought that JVM is waiting for all threads under application to be terminated. 
In this case after `Thread.sleep(100)` is executed program shut down and I don't see `10` in a console.

Note: If I will use custom Executor like `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);` it will wait until shutdown, but with `Schedulers.newThread()` it won't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Schedulers.newThread()` will act as a daemon thread: if main thread finishes - daemon thread won't stop JVM from shutdown. In this example this new (daemon) thread will go into `print` method and will be waiting for a 5 seconds, while main thread will be waiting just for a 0.1 sec and will just finish `main` method execution. That's all...

Comment: Thanks, it is an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If not using ThreadPool you must wait (join) the created Thread yourself, see the [join method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-); there are some overloading.

You can get all explanation in the javadoc about [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) which offers you this kind of management.

Let me know if you need further info.

Comment: How can I do it and why is it occurs? Can you edit your answer with that?

Comment: I just completed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, Executors.defaultThreadFactory()));

        Observable.interval(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .doOnNext(word -> System.out.printf("%s uses thread %s%n", word,
                        Thread.currentThread().getName()))
                .subscribeOn(scheduler)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnNext(word -> System.out.printf("%s uses thread %s%n", word,
                        Thread.currentThread().getName()))
                .subscribe();
    }
```